# How to validate public hash key of google managed ssl certificate while doing http request to server in python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ssl, urllib3, public-key-pinning

I am using the google app engine for my application and it has google managed SSL certificates enable. Google automatically renews it also before expiration.

One thing I noticed that google uses the same private key for creating or renewing the new certificates so the hash of the public key is not changing.

Now what I wanted to do is validate this public key hash while doing a request to the server in python using urllib3 or with any other library. So that if it doesn't matches with the hash of the incoming public key hash it fails the request and alerts me about me.

I went through a lot of links about pinning and all but didn't able to find anything for such comparison. Can somebody help me here? Specifically how to do it with python3?

PS: I don't have the certificate or its private key since it is managed by Google (didn't find any option too to download the current certificate from the google app engine). I already have the hash of the public key as `Pin SHA256: xxxxxxxxxxxx`

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You mention "while doing a request to the server". Libraries such as URLLIB3 verify certificates when establishing an HTTPS connection. Are you asking how to verify the site's certificate before connecting? You can download any public site's certificate. In your web browser click on the padlock for the site. The program `openssl` also supports downloading a site's certificate. Verifying an SSL certificate is fairly complicated, are you sure that you want to do this in your own code? I recommend using libraries that do this for you already.

Comment: If I am correct URLLIB3 can check the certificate fingerprint which will be changed with every certificate. I wanted a way where I can assert check the public key of the certificate while establishing an HTTPS connection. @JohnHanley

Comment: Write some code and try. We can help you with software your write.